# Grid layout - assigning side bar and main conent with full height rest from header and footer?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a layout, which should occupy the height of header and footer leaving rest to the main container. ( sidebar, content ). but not able to archive this. any one help me?

I do not have fixed height for both header and footer. ( it should only occupy content height )

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header  header"
    "sidebar content"
    "footer  footer";
  height: 100vh;
}

.header { grid-area: header; background-color: yellow; }
.sidebar { grid-area: sidebar; background-color: gray; }
.footer { grid-area: footer; background-color: green;}
.content { grid-area: content; }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">header should shrink with it's content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">it should be rest of the height from header and footer</div>
  <div class="footer">footer should shrink with it's content</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>it should be rest of the height from header and footer</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/DRXfboRBE5CeMcsm?open=lib%2Fstyle.css&preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
```

`1fr` will fill the rest spaces.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header  header"
    "sidebar content"
    "footer  footer";
  height: 100vh;
}

.header { grid-area: header; background-color: yellow; }
.sidebar { grid-area: sidebar; background-color: gray; }
.footer { grid-area: footer; background-color: green;}
.content { grid-area: content; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header should shrink with it's content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">it should be rest of the height from header and footer</div>
  <div class="footer">footer should shrink with it's content</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>it should be rest of the height from header and footer</p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```